# How to add a default option with value -1 and have that selected Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

Using a select with ng-options leads to a selected option with value '?'

```
<select ng-model="somethingHere"  
        ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in options" 
        class="ng-pristine ng-valid">

    <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="0">Something Cool</option>
    <option value="1">Something Else</option>
</select>
```

I need to have

```
<option value="-1" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="0">Something Cool</option>
        <option value="1">Something Else</option>
```

How can i do this? How can i add a default option with value -1 and set it as selected.
Using

```
 <select ng-model="somethingHere"  
            ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in options" 
            class="ng-pristine ng-valid">

        <option value="-1" ng-selected> SELECT</option>

    </select>
```

does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Init the model value to the value of the default:

```
<select ng-model="somethingHere"  
        ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in options" 
        class="ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-init="somethingHere=-1">
    <option value="-1"> SELECT</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The issue with using the ng-init is that it runs even if the select is inside a div which is hidden

Comment: How do you decide if the div is visible?

Comment: I have a var to decide the same.

Comment: Infact the option.Type

Comment: I also need this and I already have a value to select. I just need the option to show and have a value of -1. It will never be initially selected.